# Wrong magic number - Uploading shapefiles to GeoServer

Tags: php, upload, geoserver

I successfully created workspace using the GeoServer REST API. But I am having problem uploading shape file.

I followed [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-examples-curl.html#uploading-a-shapefile) guide.

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H 'Content-type: application/zip' --data-binary "@D:/trash.zip" http://localhost:9090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/string/datastores/trash/file.shp
```

PHP - Equivalent

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/string/datastores/trash/file.shp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
    "file" => "@" .realpath("D:/trash.zip")
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin" . ":" . "geoserver");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/zip";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

When I run it I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number,
>   expected 9994, got 757935405

Have no clue how to upload shapefile to geoserver.
Thank you!

Comment: However, when I used Command Line Tool and executed the code, it worked perfectly. But when I try to do it with PHP, I am getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: you may need to use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); to tell curl to transfer the zip file as binary